# Simple Transformation with Linq

Tags: linq

I'm sure this is a trivial question but I couldn't find a good example. Suppose all you want to do is change one attribute for all objects in a list. I'd like to say something like:

```
List<SomeType> list = ...;

list.Select(x => x { x.Name = "Foo" } );
```

Notice the absence of the "new" keyword. I don't want to recreate objects that already exist, just execute one line of code (in this case a simple assignment) on every element of the list.

Is this possible in linq in some elegant way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Though the suggested solutions work, Linq is intended for queries. Don't abuse it.

Comment: @Doc Brown: Linq isn't only intended for queries!

Comment: @Christopher Edwards: I am pretty sure you know for what the abbreviation LINQ stands. And if you are not convinced, have a look at the link to Eric Lippert's article posted by spender.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy.  [MSDN ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) its actually just a method of the List class, but it allows for you to use Lambda expressions.

```
 list.Foreach(x => x.Name = "Foo"  );
```

Comment: Definitely not an extension. Just a standard method of List of T

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really fall under Linq if you want to mutate the collection. See [Eric Lippert's post](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) to see why.

Try [`List<T>.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-7.0)